# Fetchingdata from Cloud Firstore results in OSError when SUBPROCESS.POPEN.COMMUNICATE() method is used

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-firestore, subprocess, popen, file-descriptor

I have sample script that starts by opening a connection to firebase cloud database and retrieving the information from the database using get() method. Script then moves to a infinite loop that calls subprocess.popen.communicate() method.

Output - 
1. Data is retrieved successfully from the database .
**2. Infinite loop runs successfully for 4 minutes and then terminates with OSError: Bad File Descriptor**

```
import sys, os, time, subprocess
import google.auth.transport.requests
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore 
import datetime

def firebase_retrieve_data():   
    cred =firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount.json')   
    app=firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    db= firestore.client()

    doc_ref = db.collection(u'collection_name').document(u'doc_name')


    try:

        doc = doc_ref.get()

        firebase_admin.delete_app(app)


    except Exception as e:
        firebase_admin.delete_app(app)
        print(e)
        print(u'No such document!')

firebase_retrieve_data()

while(True):
    x=subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds= True, shell=True).communicate()
```

Although both pieces seem independent of each other and OSError is generated due to subprocess.popen.communicate() method, I suspect error is related to get() function that retrieves the data from the database. Reason I say this is because, while the script was running I ran following command to get list of active connections in the background

```
   "sudo lsof -i -n | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"
```

**I found out that get() function opens a connection to database that remains open for about 4-5 minutes(I assume thats the timeout for the database connection). As soon as this database connection closes, the script fails with   OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor on line**

x=subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds= True, shell=True).communicate()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

**I suspect that it has something to do with improper closing of database connection** but all the firebase examples or python firebase documentation I see has no mention of proper closing of database connection()

Plus, I am failing to understand the reason of how firebase database connection should effect call to subprocess.popen.communciate() method

Comment: Environment Used -  python 2.7.10 ,   Operating System -  macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6, Database Used -  Cloud Firestore

Comment: Tried to use os.popen3("pwd") command instead of subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds= True, shell=True).communicate() , SAME ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
os.system("pwd")
```

instead of

```
subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds= True, shell=True).communicate()
```

This Works . However, still don't know the reason why subprocess.Popen.communicate() and os.popen() throw an error